# In R, using round() to 2 d.p. returns 0, would like it to the nearest d.p. in this case?

Tags: r, rounding

The round function is returning 0 with digits = 2 for one of my variables, but digits = 3 returns 0.003. Is there easy code to get it to return .003 in this one case?

the actual number is -0.002857143.

I've tried using format() with nsmall = 3 or 4, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? Could you try rounding the number by yourself to 2 decimal places? What do you get?. Now try rounding to 3 decimal places.

Comment: `signif(x, 1)` will give you a single significant digit, if that's what you want?

Comment: Ricardo's answer will work, but you are asking the wrong question.  Use rounding only when you want a certain level of precision in your output.  If you want 2 digits, then zero **is** the correct output for `0.003` .  Do not foul up your statistics / error analysis on the basis of aesthetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom round using a while loop:

```
round.cust <- function(true.n){
  round.n = 0
  j = 3
  while(round.n==0){
    round.n = round(true.n, j)
    j = j + 1
  }
  return(round.n)
}
```

This will increase the number of digits (starting from 3) until the round gives something different from 0.

Comment: You probably should put a limit on `j` so it never tries to get to 35 sig figs

Comment: That's up to OP to decide whether he want that or not, but it's just put `round.n==0 & j<35` inside the `while()`